# How do I put the <center>content</center> in bottom of a div with min-height?

Tags: html, css

This is what I've tried. Is there any simple way to do this?

```css
.minh {
min-height:70px;
border:1px solid #f00
}
.btm {
  vertical-align:bottom;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="minh">
  <center class="btm">This goes to bottom</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `<center>`. That's what CSS is for.

Comment: you want to use  "text-align: center;" instead in your css